# Create a dictionary of schemas in Databricks for a parameterized notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, schema, databricks

I have a notebook in Databricks that looks as below.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Define the input path. Files looks like COMPANYX_20220113.csv
input_path = '/mnt/stackoverflow/source/COMPANYX*.csv'

# Define the output path
output_path = '/mnt/stackoverflow/raw/COMPANYX'

# Read in the CSV file
raw_df = spark.read.csv(path=input_path, schema=schema, sep=';', header=False, inferSchema=False)

# Write the DataFrame in the delta format - one time operation, commented out after first run
filtered_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(output_path)

# Create a delta table - one time operation, commented out after first run
spark.sql(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stackoverflow.RAW_COMPANYX USING DELTA LOCATION '{output_path}'")

# Create temporary view to use as source table in the merge
filtered_df.createOrReplaceTempView("new_rows")

# Save the temporary table in the delta table using merge logic
spark.sql(f"MERGE INTO stackoverflow.RAW_COMPANYX d \
          USING new_rows s \
          ON d.DATUM = s.DATUM \
          AND d.FORNR = s.FORNR \
          AND d.AVD = s.AVD \
          AND d.KBESTNR = s.KBESTNR \
          AND d.VAGNNR = s.VAGNNR \
          WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET * \
          WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT * \
          ")
```

My question is the following:
This notebook should parameterize the different csv files that can land in `source`. COMPANYX, COMPANYY and COMPANYZ all lands their csv files here, but they all have different schemas.

For the `schema=schema`, I would like to know how to rotate the schema used when reading csv files from a dynamic path.

I was thinking of creating a dictionary of schemas, and fetching the correct key:value pair based on the parameter sent in from, in my case, ADF when calling the notebook.

How would you go about doing this?
Any other feedback on above?

Note: I have excluded some transformations in the above script that uses `pyspark.sql.functions`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create widgets in Databricks and read the data from ADF.
2. Create one python function as below to assign the schema from dictionary of schemas which you are planning to declare.

```
def check_file_name(input_path):
    if input_path.split(".")[0].endswidth("X"):
       schema = assign_x_schema
    elif input_path.split(".")[0].endswidth("Y"):
       schema = assign_y_schema
    elif input_path.split(".")[0].endswidth("Z"):
       schema = assign_Z_schema
    return schema

schema = check_file_name(input_path)
```

There may be some better approach, this one approach i was thinking.

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: Thanks. This looks like the approach I was thinking. Out of curiosity, how would you go about and actually create this dictionary of schemas? How could that code look like and would you place it inside another notebook and import it?

Comment: I think we can declare dictionary of schemas in the notebook. 
One more approach i was thinking is store the dictionary of schemas as a json file and read the ADF and lookup and compare it in if condition and pass that as a parameter to ADB, I am not sure about this approach, since i have not tested it.